# Problem handling interruption with Raspberry Pi 4 with a DC Motor

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, interrupt

I have some troubles handling interruptions with my Raspberry Pi 4, using Python.

I have a [DC motor with an encoder](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-634.html) , I would like to make a speed control of this motor. But I have some issues with reading the encoder values with my Raspberry.

Here is the code I run :

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
HallA = 5 # GPIO pin for Hall A
HallB = 6 # GPIO pin for Hall B

GPIO.setup(HallA, GPIO.IN) #set up the input
GPIO.setup(HallB, GPIO.IN)

incmot = 0 # set up the counter
        
def encodeur_inc(channel) : #function of the interruption
    B = GPIO.input(HallB) #read the second signal
    global incmot
    if B == 1 :
        incmot = incmot +1
    else :
            incmot = incmot -1

GPIO.add_event_detect(HallA, GPIO.RISING, callback = encodeur_inc) #setting up the interruption

try :
    while True :
        print(incmot)

except :
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

The problem is that, for the same number of revolutions, I get a different number of pulses each time (from 480 to 650 pulses per revolution, while the manufacturer announces 690). I tried to identify where the problem could come from:

- It does not come from the encoder, I displayed on an oscilloscope the signals of the two outputs of the encoder, they were indeed phase quadrature rectangle waves
- The raspberry does not miss interrupts, by rising a pin high when entering the interrupt then low when leaving, I displayed on the oscilloscope the inputs and outputs of the interrupt.

```
GPIO.output(20, GPIO.HIGH) #at the beginning of the function
GPIO.output(20, GPIO.LOW)  #at the end of the function
```

So I don't see where the inconsistencies I see could come from. I you have any clue that could help me don't hesitate.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: At first I would have questioned whether python would be able to keep up, but toggling output `20` should mean that it does keep up. What is the frequency of the interrupts? (How fast does your DC motor turn?)

Comment: It looks like Python keeps up. The maximum motor speed is 251 rotation per minute. The frequency of the interrupts is about 3 kHz

Comment: So, is `B` ever not `1`? ie when rotating the motor to obtain an incrementing `incmot`, if `B` is ever not `1`, then `incmot` will be decremented. Can you tell if this happens? This would account for the difference.

Comment: It happens, when moving froward B is 1, moving backward B is 0

Comment: Yes, I know that is the theory, but if you are expecting `incmot` to increment from `0` to `690`, but you only get `650`, then if it were decremented 40 times, then that would explain the difference. Can you do the experiment? Can you get the motor rotating and, eg add `print(-1)` just after `incmot = incmot -1`?

Comment: I misspoke, when I do my tests I run the engine more than one lap. So the ```incmot ```variable can take values between ```-5000 ``` and ```+5000``` approximately, with the various tests I did. I can't do the experiment because I don't have the motor with me, however I did the forward and backward tests

Comment: Well, do the experiment when you have the motor. I just wanted to check for glitches. If you run the motor forwards and ever see `print(-1)`, then you can tell that something is not reliable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this tomorrow and share the results

Comment: @quamrana I've run the experiments you suggested. There are glitches with the ```incmot```, when running forward I have some few decrementations. I've looked into it deeper with an oscilloscope, I may have found where the problem comes from : The ```encodeur_inc``` function is not always triggered at the same time (some time when ```B``` is up, other time just after it has fallen. I'm trying to look for a way to avoid this issue

Comment: Yes, That's what I was thinking. I realised you said its was quadrature encoded, so it depends on what the latency of the interrupts are. Perhaps you need to rethink this and use a separate process (multiprocessing) to poll both `HallA` and `HallB`.

Comment: Thanks ! I will look into it. For the moment, I'm trying to translate a bit `Hall B` so that the glitch is minimised. I've also thought about adding logic gate to avoid reading `Hall B` during the interruption, though I haven't come to a circuit that would cover both forward and backward situtation

Comment: You could have a latch which latches HallB on the rising edge of HallA.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @quamrana, I understood where the problem came from. When the program was interrupted, the time taken to execute the interrupt was variable and, going clockwise, `Hall B` could be at `1` or `0`, instead of `1` all the time.

To get around this problem, using a D latch allows Python time to execute the interrupt and correctly read whether the engine is moving forward or backward. `Hall A` is the clock of the latch and `Hall B` is the data.